# using Actions inside the input helper

Tags: ember.js

Using the action helper works fine inside a DOM element:

`<input value="123" {{action "someAction" on="click"}}`

But then let's say you are using the input helper to generate your input field:

`{{input value=123}}`

And you want to stick the very same action onto this input helper..

The [docs](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/templates/input-helpers/#toc_actions) say:

" To dispatch an action on specific events, such as enter or key-press, use the following

`{{input value=123 key-press="updateFirstName"}}` "

And yet..

This code does nothing:

`{{input type="text" value=123 click="someAction"}}`

I also tried this:

`{{input type="text" value=123 action="someAction" on="click"}}`

I'm slowly going insane. Can someone point me to the correct way of using actions inside the Ember input helper?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the `Actions` section in the following page: https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/yield

Comment: I've heard a lot of people say that they are using the non-ember `<input...` these days - in which case you would use normal action syntax.

Comment: I tried using the non-ember `<input>` and the action works fine, but then, I lose the "context awareness" and the data I need inside the input doesn't reload when the model changes :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{{input value=123 key-press="updateFirstName"}}
```

The above code will work fine. make sure `updateFirstName` is in the required context like if its in template then it should be present in controller or if its in component then it should be present in component.js file.

For click handler, you can try like the below.

```
{{input value=appName click=(action "onClick")}}
```

You can have look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/93433fc4e3957a04427dfe6f2b638a7b?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C).

Comment: It was the parentheses!  `(action "onClick")` worked inside the input helper.

I couldn't find any reference to that syntax anywhere... Very good to know for the future! Thanks for your help :)